# tomcat crashing due to memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, hbase

tomcat is crashing due to memory leak. Here is the catalina.out. Based on the below log, any thoughts which thread is causing and possible fix

```
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] appears to have started a thread named [hbase-tablepool-168-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] appears to have started a thread named [hbase-tablepool-169-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] appears to have started a thread named [IPC Client (47) connection to ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal/XX-XX-XX-XX:60020 from tomcat] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] appears to have started a thread named [IPC Client (47) connection to ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal/XX-XX-XX-XX:60020 from tomcat] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] appears to have started a thread named [IPC Client (47) connection to ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal/XX-XX-XX-XX:60020 from tomcat] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] appears to have started a thread named [IPC Client (47) connection to ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal/XX-XX-XX-XX:60020 from tomcat] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] appears to have started a thread named [hbase-tablepool-170-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$1] (value [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$1@1dba6717]) and a value of type [sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.Encoder] (value [sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder@38c62640]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

SEVERE: The web application [/testapp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$1] (value [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$1@1dba6717]) and a value of type [sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.Encoder] (value [sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder@58f950de]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 07, 2014 2:51:39 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Comment: You best bet should be getting the thread dump (if you could) before the crash. And revisit your thread pool/local related code. And consider upgrade to latest Tomcat or Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

HTablePool seems to be deprecated, but whoever created it (hopefully a Servlet or Filter) should call `close()` in the `destroy()` method.